# How to convert a string with a period character to an int?

Tags: c#, string

How do you convert a string with a period character to an int?

I have to convert strings like "`1924.912`" to int's, but the `int.Parse()` and `Convert.ToInt32()` methods don't work here.

Comment: "1924.912" doesn't contain a comma... do you know which culture you're expecting to parse this value as?

Comment: Strings with a comma, or period?

Comment: That looks like a full stop, not a comma, which could have a totally different meaning, can you be clear bout which it is.

Comment: You need one integer result or comma is a separator for set of ints?

Comment: Sorry I meant strings with a period.
I need one integer result, the diffrent strings are already separated.

Comment: @Sydephix: and what result are you expected 1924 or 1924912?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Double.Parse() and then convert result to int.

```
var result = (int)Double.Parse("1924.912");
```

Optionally you can specify decimal separator because its local specific.

If you want get 1924912 from "1924.912" you can achieve this by replacing "." by "":

```
  string s = "1924.912";
  int result = int.Parse(s.Replace(".", ""));
  result.Dump();
```

Will print 1924912.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "1924.912";
var mass = str.Split('.').Select(x => x).ToArray();
```

Or this:

```
var str = "1924.912";
var mass = str.Split('.');
```

To have all decimal like int use next:

```
var str = "1924.912";
var mass = str.Replace(".","");
```

Comment: I only get the first value (1924) in the int.
I acctually need them both in the same int (1924912)

Comment: @Sydephix: use following: int.Parse(s.Replase(".", "")). see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
string value = "34690.42724";
Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double.Parse(textBox1.Text.Replace(".",","))
```

Comment: This also only returns me the first value in the int. I acctually need them both in the same int

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the string `"1924.912"` to the integer `1924912` disregarding the period you can use this expression where you simply remove any periods in the string before doing the conversion:

```
Int32.Parse("1924.912".Replace(".", String.Empty))
```